# Is there anyway to know that in some folder some file just got created or deleted?

Tags: file, winapi, hook, appearance

I thinking about some global hook, but googling for "file create hook" gave me nothing.

I doing folder explorer in my prog... and I would like to **add / remove** files from visual representation in my prog as soon as they got **added / deleted / appeared (for network folders)**, instead of running loop to scan the folder all the time.

Is that possible? I hope for some WinAPI solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465) which notifies you of changes in a specific directory.

Also you can use [`SHChangeNotifyRegister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120), which is a shell feature and also works for "shell" forlders..

I suggest to read the following article: [Understanding ReadDirectoryChangesW - Part 1](http://qualapps.blogspot.de/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html)

Comment: Looks like `SHChangeNotifyRegister` is what I need. Thank you.